# Why my file gets deleted from /tmp directory on LINUX?

Tags: linux, tmp, sles

(Linux Sles12 OS)
After running command `kinit` to create a Kerberos ticket,
I run `klist` and I see the file is stored at: `/tmp/krb5cc_123456789`
its seems like after a random short time (few min/sec) the file gets deleted.
how can I find what is responsible for the deletion of this file?

Thanks!

I searched and saw that the file /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf is responsible for tmp deletion policy however it is with default setting means nothing gets deleted.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Everything inside `/tmp` is intended to do that. If you really want to know who deleted the file you could take a look at https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl

Comment: on top right corner you have menu with more 'stack overflow' groups. Please go to 'Unix & Linux'. You are very welcome :)